# Cycles procedural rough brick material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I'm trying to create a cycles material for the exterior of Hogwarts castle, like the first picture

I'm aiming for:

- Procedural bricks (probably a brick texture)
- Bump/heightmap for the bricks
- Distortion, so the bricks aren't perfect

[image]

Here's my current "progress":

[image]

Comment: So what specifically are you having an issue with?

Comment: Welcome to BSE, what's the question precisely?

Comment: Basically, how can I make a cycles shader that looks like the bricks on the castle above?